# How to copy function in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sqitch

I want to write sqitch deploy script to create new version of trigger. To ensure that revert script will revert function to previous version, I'd like to make a backup of this function. Is there any way to copy (RENAME TO is not working!) trigger function with new name?

Comment: [pg-proc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-proc.html)? You are interesting in `proname` and `prosrc` columns I guess.

Comment: If you use [sqitch rework](https://github.com/sqitchers/sqitch/blob/develop/lib/sqitch-rework.pod), the revert script will be a copy of your original deploy script.

Answer (score 2):

RENAME TO should work.   Are you forgetting parentheses or including them on the other side?

Parentheses with alter table rename are a little tricky:

```
postgres=# create function test() returns bool language sql as $$ select true; $$;
CREATE FUNCTION
postgres=# alter function test() rename to old_test();
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: alter function test() rename to old_test();
                                                ^
postgres=# alter function test() rename to old_test;
ALTER FUNCTION
```

If that is not enough, then you could `DO` and `EXECUTE` the output of pg_get_functiondef after parsing and renaming it:

```
select * from pg_get_functiondef('old_test'::regproc);
```

Comment: RENAME TO changes all references to renamed trigger function in CREATE TRIGGER statements, so I can't use it to make backup.